# Date picker show format differently when publish as a web-based form in SharePoint Library

Tags: 2007, infopath, administration, forms-services, configuration

I have a Infopath form that contain a date picker.

I set the date picker's date format to be 'DD/MM/YYYY'.

When I preview the Infopath form, the date format is correctly displayed.

However, when I publish it as a web-based Inforpath form in the SharePoint library, the display become 'MM/DD/YYYY', which is not what I have set.

Appreciate any help rendered.

Comment: Hi, might be [this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/57644/infopath-decimal-field-not-maintaining-decimal-preceding-in-sharepoint-library/57885#57885) would be of more help?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct formats according to different settings

Infopath is the client application rendering dates according to (client/machine/Windows) **Regional settings** set in **Control Panel** > **Regional and Language Settings** > **Regional Options** tab > Standards and Formulas > Customize * > **Date** tab in (in **Customize Regional Options** dialog window) > *Short date format**  which you can change by pressing **Customize...** or choosing from listbox options button there. See Fig.1.

[image: Fig 1. Client machine regional settings (used by client Infopath forms)]

**Fig 1. Client machine regional settings (used by client Infopath forms)**

Sharepoint shows dates according to (Sharepoint server site) **Regional settings** < **Site settings** (in **Site Administration** section) < **Site actions**, on ribbon, in browser:

- < sharepoint_site >/**_layouts/regionalSetng.aspx**

which again one can set to whatever settings one would wish. Cf. Fig.2

[image: Sharepoint site regional settings]

**Fig 2. Sharepoint site regional settings**

Update:
So, I navigeted in browser to a sharepoint site > **Site actions** >  **Site Settings** > **Regional settings** (under **Site Administration** section) > in **Locale** listbox changed from 
**English (United States)** to **English (United Kingdom)** and the format of date shown in browser (used by Sharepoint) became the "correct" one  (changed from previous '**MM/DD/YYYY**' to '**DD/MM/YYYY**', which is what I have set)

**Update:**
It worked for me in Sharepoint online 2010 (Office 365) while the found on internet solutions of setting date format in code did not work
Note that I wrote about machine operating system and sharepoint site's regional settings, not formatting used in Infopath (date picker control)  itself

**Update2:**
Just to second my guess that the same Infopath form uses different settings.
If it is run in browser, i.e. through/by **IPFS** Sharepoint Server 2010's **Infopath Form Services**), then it uses sharepoint settings and when as Filler/client application then local/client machine Windows settings.
 For example, in the same form username() in browser shows my sharepoint username (i:0#.f|membership|gennadyvanin@gennadyvanin.onmicrosoft.com) and run as Filler/client form the username from client machine Windows (Administrator).

[image: eEdit the form in browser or Microsoft Infopath]

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution but it does not work. Any clues to know which is the offending one - the time setting in the OS, or the SharePoint Settings or the InfoPath Settings?

Comment: Hmmm, worked for me. Though, there are at least 4 places with regional settings possibly involved which are in: 1)server's operating system; 2)sharepoint site; 3)Infopath ("Format..." button in Dat Picker control); 4)client machine's operating systems, they are many

Comment: Yeah, I can only set the settings in all your places except the 1)Server's operating system, wonder if that could be the reason for not working.

Comment: By the way, could it also be some settings that we need to set inside the Internet Explorer in order to reflect the date?

Comment: I do not see regional settings in Internet explorer (why would I configure in forums user profile my date format?). There is a Language preference. This could be discriminated by using another browser. Also, if Infopath formatting is the cause then you should republish the form template. I'd like to hear what was the cause

Comment: Same goes as me. I am trying to figure out why when the web-based infopath form was saved, the date format change from DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY. Also, I was wondering if there are any other workarounds too.

Comment: How have you ended up with it? Added Update2

Comment: Thanks for the Update2. Actually, I already notice that if I publish the form as non-web form (meaning using the client to open the form, the date will be correctly rendered.) However, if I choose the web form option, the date will be reflected wrongly. I was thinking if it is possible to copy the "date configuration" of the client application settings of the form to the web application settings (Infopath Form services).