# InfoPath Decimal Field Not Maintaining Decimal Preceding in SharePoint Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-services

Here is what I have done.

I have created one new blank InfoPath Form and added (for example) 3 fields, say A1, B1, C1.

A1 = Decimal Field = Decimal Preceding : Auto

B1 = Decimal Field = Decimal Preceding : Auto

C1 = Decimal Field (Calculation C1 = A1 * B1) = Decimal Preceding : 2

Now, when I preview InfoPath forms and enter values like

A1 = 5.29

B1 = 4.23

I gets C1 = 22.38

Works fine.

I deployed it to the SharePoint Library, configured Submit Options to save data to the same library.

Now, in my library, I said Add New Item (Add Document) which opens up the InfoPath form and I entered values as below:

A1 = 5.29

B1 = 4.23

I gets C1 = 22.38

Works fine.

BUT..now when I click on submit data, in my library, in C1 column, I get 22.3767

That's the problem (why not 2 decimal only, why 4?)

This was just an example, as per my calculation, the real value is 15.67 but in my library, I'm getting it as 15.6666666666

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer!!

You need to publish your form again and check the check box for editing the column data so you can edit that column in library!!

Once it's editable, just change the decimal points to Auto, 1, 2, 3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, when I preview InfoPath forms and enter values like
>
> A1 = 5.29
>
> B1 = 4.23
>
> I gets C1 = 22.38
>
> Works fine.

Infopath preview is alwasy in local/client Filler, the data is formatted according to local regional settings of computer (Windows) where it is viewed.

> BUT..now when I click on submit data, in my library, in C1 column, I
>   get 22.3767

The Infopath browser forms can be opened from Sharepoint both in browser and in Filler. When it is opened in browser, it is showing data according to server's settings.

See more in my answer to:

- [Date picker show format differently when publish as a web-based form in SharePoint Library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/43616)

**Update:**
Currently I do not have access to any server but I do not think that it is conceptually different from possibilities of configuring it at a workstation.

Here is a screenshot from my Windows XP SP3 Control Panel (enter control in command line) > Regional and Language Settings > **Regional Options** tab > press **Customize...** button on the right of **Select an item to match its preferences, or click Customize to choose your own format:** combobox > **Numbers** tab > **No. of digits after decimal** dropdown list of choices

You can even define Euro currency for United States :)

[image: Configuring formatting options in control panel]

Comment: Ok, I got it, but your answers described for problem of date picker, what I am looking is for decimal preciseness, any solution for it now?

Comment: See update in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and neither solution works for me.

On the server, the number of decimal digits is 2, and the same for the client - but it still shows 3 in the browser.

Also, I don't want to allow others to edit the column, so can't make it editable.

Best bet is to use SharePoint Manager which does allow you to change the format, or you can use a string for that column.